# Как переместить элементы из одного стека в другой?

Tags: c++

```
struct Stack {
    int inf;         // значение элемента
    Stack *next;    // указатель на следующий эле-мент 
} *begin;            // Указатель вершины стека

struct Stack2 {
    int inf;         // значение элемента
    Stack2 *next;    // указатель на следующий эле-мент 
} *begin2;            // Указатель вершины стека
```

Comment: если нужно сохранение порядка, то через промежуточный стек.

Comment: @VladD, это как?....можно код?

Comment: while (!st1.empty())
      st_temp.push(st1.pop());
    
    while (!st_temp.empty())
      st2.push(st_temp.pop());


empty - это функция, которая определяет, не пуст ли стек. push - помещает в стек, pop извлекает из стека и возвращает как значение.

Дальше справитесь?

Comment: @KoVadim, а как это написать без STL?

Comment: @barselona1002: ну, примените логику сами, что ж вы? подумайте, (1) как взять элемент из вершины стека, (2) как добавить элемент в стек. иначе вы никогда не научитесь.